# Get file paste directory on Windows and Mac

Tags: windows, macos, clipboard, paste

I'm trying to spy on the target directory when a user pastes a file. Let's say I copy/cut a file from somewhere on my computer. Then I paste it into another place. I want to be able to know the paste target directory programmatically.

Some questions on Stackoverflow mentioned using a global hook on Windows to be notified when a paste operation happens. But it doesn't give you the paste directory.

On Mac, file drag and drop has a promised delay feature. I'm not sure about normal file copy and paste.

Kind of get stuck now. Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: On the mac you can write a script to do it; https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/MacAutomationScriptingGuide/WatchFolders.html

Comment: Thanks John, the script solution has to have the knowledge of the directory in advanced. But that's the information that I'm trying to obtain.

Comment: Okay, you can monitor the entire file system, but it's a bit more tricky; https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Darwin/Conceptual/FSEvents_ProgGuide/UsingtheFSEventsFramework/UsingtheFSEventsFramework.html. Note that it can even report changes between launches of your app.

Comment: Interesting, I will give that a go. Thanks.